# Find Order of $ U(n) $

Tags: group-theory

Let $U(n)$ be group under multiplication modulo $n$. For $n=248$, find number of elements in $U (n)$.

As I tried to do this problem. The number of required elements are $\phi(n) $. So to calculate $\phi(248) $ I first write $248$ as product of powers of primes.
So we have $248= 2^3\cdot 31$.

Since $\phi (n) = n (1- \frac{1}{p})(1-\frac{1}{q})$ , where $n=  p^iq^j$,

So $\phi (248) =248 (1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{31}) =120$.

But book says answer is $180$. What's going wrong?

Comment: The book seems to be wrong. $\varphi(248)$ is $120$.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

As [lisyarus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/135314/lisyarus) says in the comments $\varphi{(248)} = 120$, so yeah the book has a typo. Just for fun, here are the first few integers $n$ such that $\varphi(n) = 180$:

$$\varphi^{-1}(180) = \{181,209,217,279,297,362,418,434,558, \dotsc\}$$